# Writing ODS file to local machine from EG Server

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am using EG based on a SAS 9.4.2.0 installation and am trying to string a set of proc reports together using ODS LAYOUT, then have the report generated from this form the tab of an Excel file using TAGSET.EXCELXP as so:

```
ods listing close;

  ods tagsets.excelxp file='E:\myfolder\myfile.xml' 
      options(
              frozen_rowheaders='no' sheet_interval='none' sheet_name='sheet1'
              autofilter='all' autofilter_table='2');

ods layout gridded columns=2 rows = 2;

ods region;
proc report data = mydata1;
title = 'some title';
run;

ods region;
proc report data = mydata2;
title = 'some title';
run;

ods layout end;

ods tagsets.excelxp options(sheet_interval='none' sheet_name='sheet2');

ods layout gridded columns=2 rows = 2;

ods region;
proc report data = mydata1;
title = 'some title';
run;

ods region;
title = 'some title';
run;

ods layout end;

ods tagsets.excelxp options(sheet_interval='none' sheet_name='sheet3');

ods layout gridded columns=2 rows = 2;

ods region;
proc report data = mydata1;
title = 'some title';
run;

ods region;
proc report data = mydata2;
title = 'some title';
run;

ods layout end;

ods tagsets.excelxp close;

ods listing;
```

However I am getting both a warning that TAGSET.EXCELXP does not exist, but also an error that indicates SAS thinks my local drive for saving the Excel file to is a sub folder of the SAS config folder on the network.

What have I done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is the EG session profile using a server connection, or is it set to <do not use a profile> ?

Comment: hi there. it's a server connection.

Comment: Post the error message.

Comment: WARNING: TAGSET.EXCELXP does not exist

Comment: then an error where it says I dont have write access to a path of the order /SAS94/configfile/folder/folder/morefolders\E:myfolder\myexcel.xls

Comment: There is no `E:` drive on the **Unix** machine where SAS is running.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just have a typo in your program that matches the typo in the subject and body of your email?  You have left the trailing `s` off of the `tagsets` keyword.

Comment: sorry, warning was a typo you are correct...the issue is with the excel tagsets output i am specifying a local path i want to write an excel file to, however SAS is appending that file path to the UNIX config file path as above (note the change in direction of slashes) and telling me I have insufficient authorisation to write there (unsurprisingly)...what I dont understand is why it is trying to write to the UNIX box and coming up with the strange portmanteau UNIX/local directory file path as above...

Comment: Because SAS EG runs on a server, not on your desktop. EG sends the commands to the server and the results are sent back. But for ODS or any other output you need a place to store the files, where the server has access, and it does not have access to the E drive. You would then move the file over using a copy task.

Comment: so run my ODS process as is, but write to a UNIX file first, then export as a step in the job?

Comment: Essentially, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If your `E:\` path is a local path (meaning a local disk), then the SAS Server cannot see it.  You'll need to instead write that to a path that the SAS Server can see.  If you're not sure what paths the SAS Server can see, please contact your SAS administrator; depending on the installation the server may be able to see your normal network shares, or it may be limited to only certain locations.

If `E:\` is mapped to a network share, you may need to submit the network share UNC path, usually `\\organization\path\to\file\` structure or similar.

You can also use the `Copy Files` custom task in Enterprise Guide; see [There and Back Again](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2012/12/06/copy-files-in-sas-eg/), and if you're in EG 7 you can do this [from the Tasks->Data menu](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2016/11/14/copy-files-task-moved-menus/).  This would work if you write the file to your SAS Server's local storage (such as in the work directory or other local directory) and then use the copy files task to your local drive.